# How to extract value of all classes in beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a HTML file with a structure like this:

```html
<p id="01">... EU legislation and the <em>monetary power</em> of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q8901" name="European Central Bank">ECB</span>.</p>
<p id="02"><span class="person" Wikidata="Q563217">Guido Carli</span>, Governor of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q806176">Bank of Italy</span> ...</p>
```

I need to have a Python `dict` like this:

```py
{'institution': ['Q8901', 'Q806176'], 'person': ['Q563217']}
```

So I need to get the value of the `class` attribute of all `span` tags, along with their `text`. How can I do this with `bs4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I solved my problem thanks to @HedgeHog.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict


def capture_info(soup: 'BeautifulSoup') -> defaultdict:
    info = defaultdict(list)
    for i in soup.select('span[Wikidata]'):
        info[i.get('class')[0]].append(i.get('wikidata'))
    return info


html = '''
<p id="01">... EU legislation and the <em>monetary power</em> of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q8901" name="European Central Bank">ECB</span>.</p>
<p id="02"><span class="person" Wikidata="Q563217">Guido Carli</span>, Governor of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q806176">Bank of Italy</span> ...</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

info = capture_info(soup)
```

The output is:

```
{'institution': ['Q8901', 'Q806176'], 'person': ['Q563217']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your elements and iterate the `ResultSet` while appending the values to your `dict`. To extract the values of an attribute use [`.get()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). Because `class` will give you a `list` pick yours by index or key.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p id="01">... EU legislation and the <em>monetary power</em> of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q8901" name="European Central Bank">ECB</span>.</p>
<p id="02"><span class="person" Wikidata="Q563217">Guido Carli</span>, Governor of the
<span class="institution" Wikidata="Q806176">Bank of Italy</span> ...</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

d = {
    'institution':[],
    'person':[]
}

for e in soup.select('span[wikidata]'):
    d[e.get('class')[0]].append(e.get('wikidata'))

d
```

##### Output

```
{'institution': ['Q8901', 'Q806176'], 'person': ['Q563217']}
```

Comment: I don't have the list of class values! There may be more like 'treaty', 'journal' etc.

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi : This circumstance should be clearer from the question next time, but I am happy, could at least give you an idea. Cheers